# representation of MAC address in C code

Tags: c, network-programming, embedded

I often see such representation of MAC address in C code:

```
struct mac_addr {
   unsigned char bytes[6];
}
```

Why necessary put an array in a structure, why not just have an array? What benefit does this provide?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You can't assign an array in C.  But you can assign a struct.

Comment: However I always can do bytes[0]=0x00; bytes[1]=0x01.. and so on if MAC address was declared as array.

Comment: @Mark: Absolutely.  But it's nice to be able to do e.g. `mac_addr m1, m2; ...; m2 = m1;`.  There may be other reasons why they chose to encapsulate this, but this is the first reason I could think of.